# Remoção de arquivos txt em C++

Tags: c++, txt

Fiz um programa de ordenação mergesort para um txt gigante que não pode ultrapassar tal limite de memória primária definida pelo usuário, e por isso tive que dividir 1 txt em vários outros temporários, o problema é, que dependendo de quanta memória o usuário quer utilizar, o programa pode criar alguns ou vários aquivos temporários denominados "TempX.txt!" onde X é o número do arquivo temporário. A função remove("Temp.txt") remove somente se o arquivo txt tiver exatamente o msm nome, como eu faria o laço para remover os txt temporários de 1 até os números de txt?

Comment: Mas você sabe o numero exato de quantos são para remover ?

Comment: Onde está o programa ?